# triple integral over region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$D=\{x^2-2x+y^2\le 0 ,-x^2\le z \le 2-x-y\}$

**My attempt**:

The first one is a shifted cylinder with a radius : $x^2+y^2=2x$ which in polar coordinate should be $r=2cos\theta$.

Cylinder parametrization :

$$\begin{cases}
x=1+r\cos\theta \\ 
y=r\sin\theta \\ 
z=z
\end{cases}
$$

I chose $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ becouse the "shadowed" region is a circle tangent to the z-y plane.

[image]

I need to calculate :

$\int\int\int x dxdydz$

I think I can do this in two ways :

$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2cos\theta}\int_{-r^2cos^2\theta}^{2-rcos\theta-rsin\theta}r^2cos\theta dzdrd\theta$

or

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\int_{-x^2}^{2-x-y}xdzdydx$

**Questions**:

The problem is that they seem to be too hard, maybe something will simplify... but I really can't figure out how.

So my question is : Are those integral right? And if So can you give me a hint on how to solve it?

**Book Answer** : $\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: It seems all right. I don't think there is something simpler. In fact, the integrals in cartesians are not that hard.

Comment: Both of your triple integrals are correct. You can simplify things by taking the cylindrical coordinates $(x, y, z) = (1 + r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, z)$ and using the fact that $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^m \theta \cos^n \theta \,d\theta$ is non-zero only if both $m$ and $n$ are even. You'll get
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 (2 - x - y + x^2) x r \,dr d\theta =
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 (2 + 2 r^2 \cos^2 \theta) r \,dr d\theta.$$

Comment: @Maxim isn't the radius $r$ from $0$ to $2\cos\theta$ ? How you do a step between your simplification?

Comment: Different cylindrical coordinates (notice the offset in $x$). For the simplification, expand the integrand and find the terms containing odd powers of $\sin$ or $\cos$.

Comment: @Maxim I don't understand why $\theta$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$ even though the circle has an offset. what's wrong with writing $x^2+y^2=2x$ --> $r^2=2r\cos\theta$ --> $r=\cos\theta$ ?

Comment: You're using your coordinate transformation $x = r \cos \theta, \,y = r \sin \theta$. I'm saying that you can take a different coordinate transformation $x = 1 + r \cos \theta, \,y = r \sin \theta$. Substitute this into $x^2 + y^2 = 2 x$.

Comment: @Maxim Ohh Ok I understand! Thanks. But I still don't understand the angle $\theta$

Comment: Parametrize the unit disk in terms of $r$ and $\theta$. Then shift the disk by the vector $(1, 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
I=\int_0^2 dx
\int_{-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}dy
\int_{-x^2}^{2-x-y} dz x
$$
$$
=
\int_0^2 dx
\int_{-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}dy
(2-x-y+x^2) x
$$
$$
=
\int_0^2 dx
x(2y-xy-\frac12y^2+x^2y)
\mit_{y=-\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}}
$$
$$
=
\int_0^2 dx
[4x-2x^2+2x^3]\sqrt{2x-x^2}
$$
Here
$$
\int x\sqrt{2x-x^2} = -\frac13 (2x-x^2)^{3/2}-\frac12 (1-x)(2x-x^2)^{1/2}+\frac12 \arcsin(x-1);
$$
$$
\int x^2\sqrt{2x-x^2} = -\frac{x}{4} (2x-x^2)^{3/2}-\frac{5}{12}(2x-x^2)^{3/2}-\frac58 (1-x)(2x-x^2)^{1/2}+\frac58\arcsin(x-1);
$$
$$
\int x^3\sqrt{2x-x^2} = -[x^2/5-7x/20-7/12] (2x-x^2)^{3/2}-\frac78 (1-x)(2x-x^2)^{1/2}+\frac78\arcsin(x-1);
$$
Combined
$$
\int (4x-2x^2+2x^3)\sqrt{2x-x^2} dx = [-2x^2/5 -x/5-5/3](2x-x^3)^{3/2}-\frac52(1-x)(2x-x^2)^{1/2}+\frac52\arcsin(x-1),
$$
so
$$
I=\int_0^2 (4x-2x^2+2x^3)\sqrt{2x-x^2} dx = \frac52[\arcsin 1-\arcsin(-1)]=5\arcsin 1 = \frac52 \pi.
$$
This is NOT the book's answer. I suspect the book's answer is wrong.